# Which version(s) of VSTS for .dbproj files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

With which version(s) of VS2008/VSTS can I work with .dbproj files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely use [Team Edition for Database Professionals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833253(VS.80).aspx).  The bad news is that it seems you [can only use this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833253(VS.80).aspx) or of course the superset version [Team Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts2008/default.aspx) but that would set you back a lot for a team.

It would be nice if the whole team could edit these files without having to fork out for these expensive extra licenses.  On the plus side the dbproj projects can be [built using Team Build](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/09/11/vsts-2005-and-2008-building-database-projects-with-team-build.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

One good note is that recently Microsoft changed the licensing so that if you already have Team System Developer Edition you can use Team Edition for DB Pro for free (and vice versa).

[Announcement](http://www.microsoft.com/defyallchallenges/teamsystem/default.aspx?WT.mc_id=R)